# Developing different environment products, Desktop and Web (ArcGIS Pro 3 SDK and ArcGIS Experience Builder) on one machine

Tags: arcgis-pro-sdk, arcgis-experience-builder

I can't find any requirements for ArcGIS Experience Builder except Chrome version, so I guess there is no problem. I just need a machine that answers ArcGIS Pro 3 SDK requirements?

Maybe someone already developing this way?

Comment: Are you asking from a licensing perspective, or a system resources, or if there is a technical reason you can't? My best guess would be you could develop all those technologies on a single machine. There is nothing I'm aware of that would conflict.

Comment: Sorry, clarifying - I'm asking if it technically possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to develop both *Desktop* and *Web* technologies on a single machine. This question / answer is as much about the underlying technology as it is the individual Esri components.

For the web: (ArcGIS Experience Builder) [requirements](https://developers.arcgis.com/experience-builder/guide/requirements/), you'll need:

- Node.js: https://developers.arcgis.com/experience-builder/guide/install-guide/#server-install
- ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise: https://developers.arcgis.com/experience-builder/guide/install-guide/#server-install
- Optionally the ArcGIS JavaScript API for an offline installation. This requires Node.js which you already need.

For Desktop (ArcGIS Pro) [requirements](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki#requirements), you'll need:

- ArcGIS Pro / ArcGIS Pro SDK
- Microsoft .NET Runtime 6.0.5 (or higher)
- Visual Studio 2022
- Some various 3rd party assemblies

There are no problems installing the Esri components on a single machine as long as you have the system resources.
To the best of my knowledge, none of the non-Esri components conflict, and you should be able to install them on the same machine.

Comment: "Should" is the key word, of course I checked the requirements for both development environments before asking the question.
Question is more about have anybody done this or doing now?